# I would like my Memes to have higher Res

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I make original memes in Illustrator and save them at the highest possible JPEG res but it still looks grainy when posted in FB. Can you suggest another way?

Comment: facebook recompresses jpegs with (at best) medium quality on upload. You cannot get around it.

Comment: Hey TicoT! Welcome to GD.SE! If you have any questions about how GD.SE works, have a look at the [help center](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help) or feel free to ping one of us in [Graphic Design Chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/) once your reputation reaches 20. Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Comment: one does not make memes. Society does.

Comment: Educated guess: JPG is already a compression, and Facebook applies more compression to it. How about saving your memes uncompressed (PNG or BMP) and uploading those? Then only one layer of compression will be applied, and it may look a lot better.

Answer (score 2):

Facebook will only compress an image if the size is over a certain amount. The compression is much worse than if you save under that threshold. I know the banner size has to be under 100kb.

If you save at 1:1 size of the recommended size (There are a plethora of resources on the web that tell you what sizes are used for the various images) and save for medium quality then the images will not be compressed. They will not be hi-res but they will not be as bad as the compression.